# UIAlertView - choose from options

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview, uialertview

How can I create a UIAlertView that allows a user to select a single item from a list of items in my iPad app? Like a UITableView inside of a UIAlertView.

Comment: Might seem very obvious, but did you try adding the table view as a subView inside the alert view?

Comment: If this is for an iPad app, you might consider using a UIPopoverController containing a UITableViewController, rather than try to do this with a UIAlertView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use -addSubview on a UIAlertView just like any other view.  Which means that it's just a matter of getting the right dimensions, and using a ton of newline escapes to elongate the alert.